# Simple Injector: RegisterWebApiController failing to suppress DisposableTransientComponent warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I may be simplifying or misunderstanding things, so I'd like to apologise in advance if this is a really dumb question. :)

Based on the documentation and code I've seen, my understanding is that when calling `RegisterWebApiController` with Simple Injector (on `4.3.0`), the "Disposable Transient Component" warnings should be suppressed for all classes that are of type `ApiController`.

Having said that, the below code is throwing an invalid configuration error

```cs
public class SimpleInjectorConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure(
        Container container, HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(
            configuration, Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestController)));

        //Register the other required classes
    }
}
```

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Disposable Transient Component]  is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.

None of the controllers actually override the `IDisposable` method, and from what I can debug, the below code fragment (taken from the latest `Simple Injector` [source](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi/SimpleInjectorWebApiExtensions.cs)) should be getting called successfully:

```cs
registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent,
    justification:
        "Web API registers controllers for disposal when the request ends during the " +
        "call to ApiController.ExecuteAsync.");
```

The confusion comes from the fact that when I modify the `Configure` method with the below code, it does successfully suppress the warnings (i.e. It works).

```cs
public static void Configure(
    Container container, HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(
        configuration, Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestController)));

    foreach (var component in container.GetCurrentRegistrations())
    {
        component.Registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(
            DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, 
    "Web API registers controllers for disposal when the request ends during " +
        "the call to ApiController.ExecuteAsync.");
    }

    //Register the other required classes
}
```

To add to the confusion, we've used Simple Injector in a number of other projects and the warning suppression seems to work as intended in all of them but this which is why I'm thinking it's a configuration issue of some sort. I've tried comparing the projects to find what's different, but unfortunately I'm not coming up with anything as yet.

The `TestController` code is defined as

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetTestString()
    {
        return Ok("Test String from Test Controller");
    }
}
```

Anyone ever encountered this or can shed some light as to why this may be happening? Thank you!

---

### Update

Thanks to the information provided by Steven below, I managed to figure out that the issue was because of what looks like inconsistencies between `SimpleInjector` libraries.

`SimpleInjector` was on `4.3.0`, while `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi` was on `3.1.0`. Upgrading `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi` to `4.3.0` did the trick.

Comment: Can you show the code for that particular controller? Does it inherit from `ApiController`?

Comment: @Steven - added the controller code for your reference, which seems to be okay unless I'm missing something? Will keep digging to figure out why this is happening. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Steven - looks like I found the issue. The `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi` package we had installed from nuget was on version `3.1.0`. Upgrading this to `4.3.0` in line with the `SimpleInjector` package solved the issue.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason this is happening is because your Web API Controller implements both `IHttpController` and `IDisposable`, but does not inherit from `ApiController`.

Web API's `ApiController` base class registers itself for disposal (by calling `RegisterForDispose`) *inside* its `SendAsync` method. This ensures that the controller will get disposed when the request ends.

This is why Simple Injector suppresses the diagnostic warning on controllers that inherit from `ApiController`; Web API will ensure they will get disposed.

Since the registration for disposal happens *inside* the `ApiController`, it does mean that a controller that simply implements `IHttpController` (but without inheriting from `ApiController`) will never get disposed. This is why Simple Injector only suppresses this warning in the case of `ApiController` derivatives.

Because of this, you should **never** suppress this diagnostic warning on your Web API controllers without taking other prepercusions that garantee your controller is disposed.

If your controller has no meaningful dispose logic, you should remove the `IDisposable` interface from the controller. This removes the problem. It should be rare for a controller to require dispose logic, because you should typically extract this to other services; controllers should typically not depend on resources that it creates itself.

If that controller, however, does require disposal, you can override its registration to become `Lifestyle.Scoped`. This ensures the type is disposed by Simple Injector:

container.RegisterWebApiControllers(
        configuration, Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestController)));

```
container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
container.Register<MySpecialController>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = false;
```

Alternatively, you can suppress the diagnostic warning, only on that specific controller, and cook a special delegate that ensures its disposal:

```
container.GetRegistration(typeof(MySpecialController)).Registration
    .SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, 
        "We dispose manually.");

container.RegisterInitializer<MySpecialController>(c =>
    Lifestyle.Scoped.GetCurrentScope(container).RegisterForDisposal(c));
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and detailed reply @steven, much appreciated! I'll go through the code as soon as I get access to it again and will post here. I'm almost convinced that they do inherit from `ApiController` but need to double check and provide more info surrounding the controller setup if so.

Comment: If a controller inherits ApiController and is registered through RegisterWebApiControllers, you will not experience the diagnostic warning. So either one of these two conditions is false in your case.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as it provided in-depth info to what's going on. It helped me realise the issue was more to do with configuration than the actual process. Updating the question with what turned out to be the actual cause.